# How to use django-haystack SearchQueryset's narrow functionality in drf-haystack?

Tags: django, solr, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I want to use SearchQuerySet's narrow function to take advantage of fq(result caching and no impact on score) in solr in drf haystack.

I am looking for something like

http://example.com/api/v1/location/search/?narrow_by=country:Oslo

If this feature is not available(which probably isn't) what is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the docs on drf-haystack?

https://drf-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07_faceting.html#narrowing

If using the latest v1.6.0rc3 version, there is a mixin class which provides support for faceting.

Comment: But I want narrowing support without facets. For queries like text=content&facet.query=state:("New York" OR "Georgia" OR "South Carolina")

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure what you're looking for... Narrowing (at least in django-haystack terms) is used in conjunction with faceting. 
If you are referring to query facets, that is currently not supported, but in progress of being implemented.